# Adding Credits (A Decimal)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue Summing the actual values of the columns. It appears I am just being returned Row counts. I have a table of students who have taken classes and the number of credits that class was worth.

```
Create table #tempy (
        student_name varchar(50),
        class varchar(50),
        credits decimal
        )
Insert into #tempy (student_name, class, credits)
Values('Chris','Math', 0.5), ('Chris', 'Science', 0.5), ('Jill', 'Reading', 1.0), ('Sarah', 'Math',0.5)
Select student_name, Sum(credits) as credits
From #tempy
Group by student_name
Drop Table #tempy
```

Chris should have a total of `1` credit. Instead I am getting `2`.
Same with Sarah, she should be getting `.5` credits. But is getting 1 as if it is just adding row counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the size of the decimal. try `decimal(9,2)` in your create statement.

```
create table #tempy (
        student_name varchar(50),
        class varchar(50),
        credits decimal(9,2)
        )
Insert into #tempy (student_name, class, credits) Values
  ('Chris','Math', 0.5)
, ('Chris', 'Science', 0.5)
, ('Jill', 'Reading', 1.0)
, ('Sarah', 'Math',0.5)
Select student_name, credits=sum(credits)
From #tempy
Group by student_name
Drop Table #tempy
```

results in

```
+--------------+---------+
| student_name | credits |
+--------------+---------+
| Chris        | 1.00    |
| Jill         | 1.00    |
| Sarah        | 0.50    |
+--------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the precision of your `decimal` field; like that, is acting as a default `decimal(18,0)` field (18 digits with 0 decimals).

This should do:

```
Create table #tempy (
    student_name varchar(50),
    class varchar(50),
    credits decimal(5,2) -- 5 digits, 2 of them decimals
    )
```